# How to work interface optional properties in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I was reading the documentation about TypeScript and encounter this:

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
}

function createSquare(config: SquareConfig): { color: string; area: number } {
    let newSquare = {color: "white", area: 100};
    if (config.clor) {
        // Error: Property 'clor' does not exist on type 'SquareConfig'
        newSquare.color = config.clor;
    }
    if (config.width) {
        newSquare.area = config.width * config.width;
    }
    return newSquare;
}

let mySquare = createSquare({color: "black"});
```

I didn't understand why there's { color: string; area: number } after createSquare(config: SquareConfig):
Could someone explain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ":" after the function parameters indicates the return type.  This function returns an object with properties "color" and "string".

Comment: Also see https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/functions.html#return-type-annotation

Comment: So it only indicates that function are going to return an object with two properties as { color: "color",  area: any_value}, right?